# Importing FBX Created in 3ds Max Rearranges Individual Models

Tags: import, .fbx

I have been attempting to export a FBX file consisting of multiple models from 3ds Max 2019 and importing the FBX file into blender to make some changes.  Every time I have attempted this, the models looks something like what is shown in the image below:

[image]

I have attempted to perform the FBX export and the import in different ways and can never change the end result.  I could keep using 3ds Max 2019, but I would prefer to get it working with blender as well.  All the original models were done either in SolidWorks or Inventer, but I really need to use blender to alter them for my projects.

If anyone has experienced the same problem and found a solution, I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Does it import fine in other software? Can you use a different file type?

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue as well, did you happen upon a solution?